# WebBrowser with Proxy very slow

Tags: c#, proxy, browser, webbrowser-control

I am using .Net Webbrowser to login to SSL/TLS (https:// urls) website, with success. However I've noticed that if I use Proxy it become dead slow 30~50sec to load login page. I've tried the solution suggested here [C# WebBrowser Control Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035911/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-proxy) and it seems similar to this [SSL/TLS/HTTPS sites are very slow in a C#/.NET WebBrowser control, but fine in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345041/ssl-tls-https-sites-are-very-slow-in-a-c-net-webbrowser-control-but-fine-in-i) but they didn't solve my problem. So, the question is what is the best way to use Proxy with Webbrowser to login to SSL/TLS (https:// urls) website?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499568/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-webbrowser-control-without-effecting-the-system-ie-proxy?rq=1

Comment: I am not sure how those address to my issue? I did implement the solution found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353715/how-do-i-use-internetsetoption but it is very slow

Comment: may be performance issue is related with slow proxy

Comment: Nope, I've tested it... my guess it has something to do with SSL resolving certificate but not sure how

Comment: have you tried Fiddler to find difference between ie and webbrowser; one more sample code for "how to use proxy" can be found in http://1code.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest under CSWebBrowserWithProxy just download source code and unzip project